# Нерефлексивне, симметричное, транзитивное бинарное отношение

Tags: дискретная-математика

Привести пример бинарного отношения R ⊂ A × A, где
A = {a, b, c,d,e}, которое является нерефлексивное, симметричное, транзитивное, и
построить его матрицу.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Симметрия и транзитивность в непустом соотношении влекут рефлексивность, не? Если существует пара a≈b, то b≈a, и a≈a.

Comment: у меня Антирефлексивность.

Comment: Вам нужно вот эти вот свойства одновременно? Или по отдельности три примера?

Comment: Если одновременно, то как верно указал @bipll, только пустое отношение.

Comment: @vp_arth я уже составил правильною матрицу (обновил картинку)
 правьилно отношения?
(1,5)
(2,4)(2,5)
(3,3)(3,4)(3,5)
(4,2)(4,3)(4,4)(4,5)
(5,1)(5,2)(5,3)(5,4)(5,5)

Comment: 5R5 - нарушает антирефлексивность. 4R2+2R4 по транзитивности должно повлечь 2R2. Единственная правильная матрица со всеми тремя характеристиками - заполненная нулями.

Comment: @vp_arth как тогда навести пример бинарного отношения R ⊂ A × A

Comment: Если у вас есть полный оригинальный текст задания — лучше его добавить в вопрос. Задание может быть и с подвохом, а правильный ответ - нуль-матрица 5х5

Comment: @vp_arth Привести пример бинарного отношения R ⊂ A × A, где
A = {a, b, c,d,e}, которое является нерефлексивное, симметричное, транзитивное, и
построить его матрицу.

Comment: Секундочку. В задании нерефлексивное, а в впоросе антирефлексивное. Это разные вещи

Comment: @vp_arth ну я думал анти = не

Comment: Впрочем это мало что меняет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Привести пример бинарного отношения R ⊂ A × A, где A = {a,b,c,d,e},
> которое является антирефлексивное, симметричное, транзитивное

Пустое отношение.

```
 R = ∅ ⊆ A × A
```

> Построить его матрицу.

```
 R | a | b | c | d | e
---|---|---|---|---|---
 a | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
 b | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
 c | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
 d | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
 e | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

Comment: А "Пустое отношение" как-то формулами записывается?

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ @vp_arth:

Как было замечено в комментариях, антирефлексивнность ≠ нерефлексивность (см. [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Рефлексивное_отношение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))
Поэтому на диагонали могут стоять до 4 нулей:

```
 R | a | b | c | d | e
---|---|---|---|---|---
 a | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0
 b | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0
 c | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0
 d | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0
 e | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

Запись через множества:

```
R = {a, b}×{a, b} ∪ {c, d}×{c, d} ⊆ A×A
```

Таким образом, данное отношение задает *почти* разбиение множества, в отличие от отношения эквиваленции